# Is it necessary to be certified before opening a photography studio?

Tags: business, photography, nigeria

Suppose that a person is not certified as a professional photographer in Nigeria, but believes that s/he has enough personal experience to run a studio.

Is there any legal problem if such a person opens a studio in Nigeria without being certified? Is there even such a certification in Nigeria?

Comment: [Photography Business – How To Start Photography Business In Nigeria](https://www.entrepreneurs.ng/photography-business/) talks among other things about registering the business and obtaining certification of that.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed? It seems to be basically asking "what are the requirements for starting a photography business in Nigeria," which is far less of a request for specific legal advice than many other questions that do not get closed.

Comment: I agree there is no reason for this to be closed. We may or may not be able to find the relevant Nigerian law or regulation but this is just asking what the law is in a particular case.. I note this was closed unilaterally by a moderator. I call on @Dale M to reverse that action.

Comment: @Someone I disagree - the question is specifically about the *legal* requirements for starting a business. There are likely to be many national and local laws that apply and the OP is likely to act on the answers. That’s legal advice they should be seeking from their business advisor or the government.

Comment: @dale, by that standard, half or more of the questions ion this stack should be closed. That is not the policy that was agreed to on meta. A question about what the law requires in a particular situation,. with no "what should I do" is the heart of what is on topic here.

Comment: Please see and comment at https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/excessive-use-of-specific-legal-advice-closure-reason